# Finding nearest values in sql

Tags: javascript, sql, database

Moin,
help is greatly appreciated :)

Here’s  my problem: I have a JLabel with an image where I get coordinates through the user.

```
int lblX = JLabel.getMousePosition().x;
int lblY = JLabel.getMousePosition().y;
```

Now I have a database where if specific x and y coordinates are met, something opens.

My question now is how to determine the nearest coordinates inside the database. My first solution:

```
int i=1;
while(primarykey=null) {
String sql = SELECT primarykey
             FROM example
             WHERE x BETWEEN (lblX-i) AND (lblX+i)
             AND y BETWEEN (lblY-i) AND (lblY+i)
ResultSet...... 
i++;
```

It’s a start but there are a few things that are not perfect, for example it searches in a cubic shape instead of a circle.

Answer (score 0):

The formula of distance between two points P(x1, y1) and Q(x2, y2) is given by square root of `dx*dx + dy*dy`.

So you can SELECT the MIN of that.
For example using mySQL syntax:

```
SELECT primaryKey, x, y 
FROM example
ORDER BY (x-lblX)*(x-lblX) + (y-lblY)+(y-lblY) 
LIMIT 1
```

Just in your code build the query like `var sql = "SELECT ... " + lblx +" ..."` and so on

Comment: can I implement that into an sql-query. And with like a MIN? I don’t understand :)

Comment: SELECT WHERE (x-lblX)*(x-lblX) + (y-lbly)*(y-lbly) < 10*10.
Edit: you want to select the MIN of this value, not compare it to 10*10.

Comment: Im too dumb for this